# @RequestBody can not work with Map has Object as Key

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, httprequest

I am creating a simple Spring Data JPA project for testing HTTP request and found out that @RequestBody has error when out of the field is of type `Map<Object, ...>`.  In this case it is `private Map<Account, Integer> test = new LinkedHashMap<>();`
I have a Cat class:

```
@Component
public class Cat {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    private Map<Account, Integer> test = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Cat() {
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    public Cat(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
// getters and setters
```

And a Account class:

```
@Component
public class Account {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
// getters and setters
```

This is my controller for POST request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/post")
public class PostController {
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<?> postCat(@RequestBody Cat cat) {
        System.out.println("Post cat: " + cat);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(cat);
    }
}
```

I use POSTMAN to create a POST request and send JSON file as body. This is the file:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 1000
}
```

(I didn't include the Map in the JSON file)
Though the code was simple, I encountered this error:
`Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]`

After testing a few things, I notice that there are 2 ways to solve the problems(the problem was probably because of the Map field):

1. Adding `@JsonIgnore` to the `private Map<Account, Integer> test = new LinkedHashMap<>();`
2. Changing the Map to `private Map<Integer, Account> test = new LinkedHashMap<>();`
   (I guess its because @RequestBody cannot work with Map which has a user_defined Object as Key, related to its deserialization process)

Does anyone know the exact reason and explain it for me?
Thanks

Comment: Don't mix your 'DTO' classes with logic classes, and `@Component` on top of all that. Make simple models and it will work - I prefer immutable models, no setters, full constructors, no empty constructors, no problems.

Comment: Probably: how should a Map<Account, Integer> be deserialized from a json?